# Lightning Design System UI responsive on browser window resize issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds

I have developed UI with using SLDS responsive framework( https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ )
More over in entire application I have used lightning component ex: lightning:tabset (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm ). Respectively this component responsive is not working as expected on browser window resize to smaller viewport size, but responsive working fine when I refresh the application after resize the window. Could you kindly let me know what is the solution for this ?

[image]

Comment: Hard to suggest anything without looking at the code. Could you share a snippet of code using which we can try replication the error?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?